# Button from 2 images

Tags: android, image, android-layout, background

I need to build button that uses 2 images as a background - one on one. Is it possible to implement or the only way is to merge them in editor and use as single image?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this, but I'd recommend looking at using a [layer list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) drawable.